# How to get the size of a compressed file without actually compressing it [SharpZipLib]

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

In SharpZipLib we use ZipEntry like this:

```
            var fi = new FileInfo(file);
            var ze = new Sharp.Zip.ZipEntry(fi.Name);
            ze.DateTime = fi.LastAccessTime;
            ze.Size = fi.Length;
            stream.PutNextEntry(ze);

            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            var byteCount = 0;

            using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(fi.FullName))
            {
                byteCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (byteCount > 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                    byteCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                inputStream.Close();
            }
            stream.CloseEntry();
```

There is a ze.CompressedSize property but it is -1 and populated only after the CloseEntry() which creates the zip file.

Is there a way to find out the Compressed size of the zip file without putting the files and actually creating it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not auto-populated after you `CloseEntry`?

Comment: I corrected the last sentence.

Comment: `without putting the files` - no that's not possible. All compression algorithms work by reducing redundancy in the data, and it is not (can't be) known in advance to what extent that can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

> Easiest way would be to have a dummy zip file, using ZipOutputStream,
>   backed with an underlying MemoryStream. Write the file to that - make
>   sure you set the same compression factor - and close the
>   ZipOutputStream, re-open it using ZipFile, and scan the entry to
>   obtain the compressed size.

There is an example [here](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/19782/50143.aspx).